# Concatenate two variables for email subject

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to fetch the attachment data from gmail to google sheets with identifier as subject.
The subject format is such as  "Disbursement File 2022-05-14" where the date is dynamic(i.e current date). I am unable to do so, Please help me with this.

```
function importReport() {
  var v = "Disbursement File "
  var n = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox subject: v+n');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[0];
  attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mail");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    var header = csvData.splice(0, 1);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate text strings with the `+` operator like this:

```
  const threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox subject: ' + v + n);
```

...or with a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this:

```
  const threads = GmailApp.search(`in:inbox subject: ${v}${n}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to setContentType here `attachment.setContentType('text/csv');` you can remove that line oF code

Be aware that you can have different ContentType for csv file, check in console the getContentType if applicable

May be add `()` around the subject according to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190 when subject contains many terms

Try

```
function importReport() {
  // 'Disbursement File 2022-05-14'
  var v = "Disbursement File "
  var n = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var threads = GmailApp.search(`'in:inbox subject: (${v} ${n})'`);
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[0]
  console.log(attachment.getContentType())
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mail");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    var header = csvData.splice(0, 1);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```